# How to get maximum number that \newcount can hold?

Tags: tex-core, counters, number, maximum-values

Is there a command that contains greatest positive integer that `\newcount` can hold?

Comment: `\int_const:Nn \c_max_int { 2 147 483 647 }` :-)

Comment: The maximum number allowed in a register is `2^31-1=2147483647`

Comment: @bp2017 TeX uses 32-bit integers internally (both for storing count registers and dimen registers), so that value is fixed, as egreg said, `2^31-1`. The definition of `\c_max_int` in `expl3` is exactly that. It could be calculated using some clever code to do the `2^31`, but it's a constant, so it's easier to just type in the value.

Comment: @bp2017 No, that's the number of available registers, not their capacity.

Comment: Vanilla TeX has 256 count registers 0 to 255 that can hold values between -2³¹ and 2³¹ - 1 inclusively.  However, the number -2³¹ cannot directly be used, TeX complains that the number is too big. The e-TeX extensions and LuaTeX increase the number of registers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum integer allowed in a TeX `\count` register is 2147483647.

You can access it as `\number\numexpr2*\maxdimen+1\relax`, if you use e-TeX extensions.

Comment: I wonder how `16383.99998pt` becomes `1073741823` when `\maxdimen` is treated as `\numexpr`. Is it some kind of weird rounding that takes place? Sum of five-digit integer and 5-digit decimal  somehow becomes an integer of 10 digits, yet the resulting integer is roughly 1/3 less than the decimal number if the decimal point were to be removed.

Comment: @bp2017 Dimensions are stored in “scaled points”: 1pt is 65536 scaled points. The number is converted to points when showing the dimension. When a `\dimen` register is used in the context of integers, the value in scaled points is used. Lengths are limited to `2^30-1`.

Comment: @bp2017 Did I say that lengths must be positive?

Answer (score 10):

While investigating a little I found out some interesting things (for me at least) and a way to get the maximum value of a count register. (This answer will use Knuth TeX, so no `\numexpr` or anything, but of course it works with e-TeX too.)

TeX uses signed 32-bit integers internally. In a signed 32-bit integer, numbers range from `-231` and `231-1`, and their order in increments of one is:

```
%                      sign change V
0, 1, ..., 2147483646, 2147483647, -2147483648, -2147483647, ..., -1
```

However TeX doesn't let you input a number larger than `231-1`:

> [image]

However if you store `231-1` in a `\counter` and `\advance\counter by 1` you do get `-231`. As Frank says in the comment below and Karl in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502989/134574), Knuth didn't add arithmetic overflow check to TeX's `\advance` for efficiency reasons. However this opens you to do some devious tricks :-)

You can exploit that to brute-force your way into finding out what the value of the maximum integer is. You can add one to a counter until its sign changes. When the sign changes, the previous value was the maximum integer. To make things faster you can start with larger steps, and reduce the step size until you find out which value is the maximum. The code below does that (pretty quickly):

```
\newcount\maxcount
\newcount\tmp

\def\gobble#1{}
\def\addloop#1{%
  \advance\maxcount by #1 % Add to the counter
  \ifnum\maxcount<\tmp % If it is negative
    \advance\maxcount by -#1 % undo
    \expandafter\gobble % and return
  \else
    \tmp\maxcount % otherwise save the value
    \expandafter\addloop % and try again
  \fi{#1}}
\def\getmaxcount{%
  \maxcount=0
  \tmp=0
  \addloop{1000000}% Faster
  \addloop{1000}% Slower
  \addloop{1}% Slowest
}

\getmaxcount
\showthe\maxcount

\bye
```

First we initialise two counters as zero, then we start by stepping the `\maxcount` counter by some value. If the stepped value makes `\maxcount` negative (*i.e.,* it becomes smaller than `\tmp`), then we passed the sign-change boundary and need to backtrack. Otherwise, try again. We can start doing that for large values, so that it arrives to the limit faster, and then reduce the step to find out the exact match.

The terminal output for the code above is:

```
C:\Users\Phelype\tex.sx>tex test.tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=tex)
(./test.tex
> 2147483647.
l.25 \showthe\maxcount

?
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Cool trick! I imagine this is system-dependent behaviour, but the TeXbook seems to be silent on arithmetic overflow. I imagine that depending on the compilation options, one may just get an overflow error from the language's runtime system, though I haven't been able to get an error with any of the TeX implementations, even tex-fpc with (allegedly) arithmetic overflow check on. This seems to stem from the modification to `cur_val` in §1238. I wonder why TeX doesn't catch overflow here… potential bug report in TeX? :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I imagined this would be system-dependent, as it depends on how the integer is represented in the memory. If I do the same trick in Fortran it works the same (even with overflow checking on). The same goes if I try to input `2147483648` directly in the source: the compiler (gfortran) will complain about it. However, after you mentioned a bug report I investigated a little further, and TeX _does_ catch arithmetic overflow, but not with `\advance`: `\tmp=1073741824 \multiply\tmp by 2 `. Thanks for the heads-up, I will report :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik don't bother to report, I'm fairly sure it is documented by Don that not all overflows are caught for efficiency reasons

Answer (score 3):

Frank is correct. In section 104 of tex.web is this text:

> The present implementation of \TeX\ does not check for overflow when dimensions are added or subtracted. This could be done by ... but the chance of overflow is so remote that
>   such tests do not seem worthwhile.

The same statement is on page 660 of Digital Typography, The Final Errors of TeX article.

I think Knuth has reiterated that point elsewhere also, perhaps in one of the tune-up reports, where the question was about crashing TeX with devious arithmetic, but I can't find that one now ...

Comment: Ah yes, it's in “The TeX Tuneup of 2008” [here](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-2/tb92knut.pdf#page=2): _Let me also observe that I never intended TeX to be immune to vicious “cracker attacks”; I only wish it to be robust under reasonable use by people who are trying to get productive work done. […] For instances of the philosophy that I had while writing these programs, see for instance TEX §9 and MF §9, which say that I expected the programs to be run with arithmetic overflow interrupt turned on; […] MF §930, “users aren’t supposed to be monkeying around with really big values.”_